# Nearest Neighbor with Complex Numbers

Tags: matlab, distance, nearest-neighbor, euclidean-distance

How to use the functions searchknn with vectors made of complex mubers?

If I do

```
A=[3 3]; B=[3 1]; knnsearch(A, B)
```

The function works (output =19. But if add an imaginary part, the function is no longer able to compute distances

```
A=[3 3]; B=[3 1+1i]; knnsearch(A, B)
```

I get:

Error using KDTreeSearcher/knnsearch (line 143)
Complex data is not allowed.

By the way, the norm I need is the simple norm in the complex plane: |x - y|^2 = (Re(x) - Re(y))^2 +  (Im(x) - Im(y))^2

Comment: What about converting the imaginary dimension to a real one? So a n dimensional complex number will become a 2n dimensional real number

Comment: That is what I have done in the end. Thank you. I thought there must be some option to specify the type of distance to be used, but maybe that`s not possible.